# How to divide a Web Form in two Columns?

Tags: html, css, zoho

I am very new to HTML5. There is an HTML5 code generated by Zoho CRM that allows me to embed a web form on my page with the CRM "Create Account" process. It works fine, but the fields are in one column and I would like to split them into two columns.

What do I need to modify?

The fields (in one column) are:

```
  <div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='First_Name'>Nombre<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='First_Name' name='First Name' maxlength='40'></input><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Last_Name'>Apellido<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Last_Name' name='Last Name' maxlength='80'></input><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Mobile'>Número Móvil<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Mobile' name='Mobile' maxlength='30'></input><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Country'>País<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Country' name='Country' maxlength='100'></input><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Email'>Correo Electrónico<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' ftype='email' id='Email' name='Email' maxlength='100'></input><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Street'>Kgs cosechados promedio mes<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Street' name='Street' maxlength='250'></input><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Company'>Nombre de la Pisc&iacute;cola</label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Company' name='Company' maxlength='200'></input><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Description'>Comentarios</label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><textarea id='Description' name='Description'></textarea><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
```

How can I divide a Web Form in two columns?

Comment: I don't understand why there are more than 6500 characters in this question, is it really so complex to explain? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Nope... I think it's not that complex. Since I don't really know enough about styles and html5, I preferred to include the full code.

Comment: So you imagine that we have to give you an answer in 50 pages of text, to explain to you how to produce HTML and CSS?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm leaving out some of the relevant styling code, but I've only left what I'd think has to do with the fields I want to go from one to two columns

Comment: I don't see your 2 columns, I see a mountain of lines of code on which no one wants to spend hours dissecting them.

Comment: Please note that "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers." (see the [tour]), a certain level of knowledge is assumed. There should also be a demonstrated attempt to solve the problem rather than just giving us code and expecting us to fix it. Further more how exactly do you want to split it into 2 colums?

Comment: It was an auto generated code from Zoho CRM. I'm just trying to modify some components to look more atractive in my web page.

Comment: There are 8 div classes, I would like to divide it in two columns of 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CSS property, columns, which might be what you want:

```css
form {
  columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='First_Name'>Nombre<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='First_Name' name='First Name' maxlength='40'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Last_Name'>Apellido<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Last_Name' name='Last Name' maxlength='80'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Mobile'>Número Móvil<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Mobile' name='Mobile' maxlength='30'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Country'>País<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Country' name='Country' maxlength='100'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Email'>Correo Electrónico<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' ftype='email' id='Email' name='Email' maxlength='100'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Street'>Kgs cosechados promedio mes<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Street' name='Street' maxlength='250'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Company'>Nombre de la Pisc&iacute;cola</label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Company' name='Company' maxlength='200'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Description'>Comentarios</label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><textarea id='Description' name='Description'></textarea>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Alternatively, if you want the contents to flow not down the first column and then down the second but across, left to right and then down to the next row, you could look into flex or grid.

Here's a simple grid. Of course you will want to add stuff to give the correct width and so on:

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='First_Name'>Nombre<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='First_Name' name='First Name' maxlength='40'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Last_Name'>Apellido<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Last_Name' name='Last Name' maxlength='80'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Mobile'>Número Móvil<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Mobile' name='Mobile' maxlength='30'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Country'>País<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Country' name='Country' maxlength='100'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Email'>Correo Electrónico<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' ftype='email' id='Email' name='Email' maxlength='100'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Street'>Kgs cosechados promedio mes<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Street' name='Street' maxlength='250'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Company'>Nombre de la Pisc&iacute;cola</label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Company' name='Company' maxlength='200'></input>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='zcwf_row'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:20px; font-family: "Open Sans";'><label for='Description'>Comentarios</label></div>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld'><textarea id='Description' name='Description'></textarea>
      <div class='zcwf_col_help'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @A Haworth. It is exactly what I needed. I think it will be a very useful answer for all those who want to integrate Zoho CRM with their website through a more modern and pleasant form. Thanks